# Why is type casting not solving this VBA Overflow error

Tags: excel, vba, overflow

I've read many of the posts on VBA Overflow errors and am still having troubles.  Looking for help.  The last line in the following code snippet is generating an overflow error.  I've tried lots of type casting and nothing is working.

What has me suspicious is this worked fine for a long while.  And all of the sudden, it starting failing.  Likely due to a change elsewhere.  I'm struggling to see if I just have a coding error, or if I'm somehow corrupting memory with my program.  Is it possible I'm using User Types in the wrong way?  I've been using VBA for a long time but it's been a while since I used User Types.

Finally, I can put a breakpoint before the offending line of code and execute this exact code with a debug.print in the immediate window.  It works fine.  Stepping into the code fails.

Would love any help you can provide.  Thanks.

btw, I'm running MSOffice on a Mac.

```
Sub create_3d_data()  
  
  Dim iPt As Integer ' point counter
  Dim iPoly As Integer ' poly counter
  Dim iKeystone As Integer 'keystone counter
  Dim theta As Single 'segment angle as we sweep the ring circle
  Dim segment_angle As Single, temp As Single
  
  iPt = 0: iPoly = 0: iKeystone = 0
  
  For iRing = 0 To user_ring_count - 1
    temp = CSng(User_Rings(iRing).number_of_segments)
    segment_angle = 3.14159 * 2# / temp                <----- Overflow Error
```

Here are some other definition code snips:

```
'in a separate Module in this VBAProject
Type User_Ring
  bottom_elevation As Single
  thickness As Single
  inside_radius As Single
  outside_radius As Single
  number_of_segments As Integer
  offset As Single
  edge_length As Single
  pattern As String
  spacer_size As Single
  spacer_color As Long
End Type
```

and

```
'in the Declarations section of the same workbook as the troubling code above
Dim User_Segments(10) As User_Segment
Dim User_Rings(30) As User_Ring
Dim user_ring_count as Integer
```

Comment: What's the value of `temp` when it fails?  It would really help to post a self-contained reproducible example for others to try.  There's really no way for us to test this otherwise.

Comment: The other issue is the code mixes Single and Double data types. segment_angle and temp are Single ... but 3.14159 and 2# are Double. As Tim commented above ... the value of temp is key ... if it means the calc is smaller/larger than a Single can contain, hence the overflow error. Suggestions are 1) to try Double data types or 2) add code to check whether the calculation is outside bounds of single and then manage the exception appropriately. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/data-type-summary

Comment: temp has a value of 12 or 24.  It's really small.  I will create a self contained snipet to help.

Comment: MS documentation says that the Double data type is the most efficient one to use for floating point calculations. I found this while trying to find confirmation what 2# stands for. It seems to be out of use. I remember it as Long. Isn't 2! a Double? In a chain multiplication the overflow can occur at any point and the sequence of execution may well change depending upon the CPU's mood (almost literally: CPU's don't tackle the same task the same way by default).

Comment: Also, I tried Segment_angle= csng(3.14159)*csng(2)/Csng(user....   and it still fails.  If I type cast ever variable in the equation to the same type as the result, should it not work?

Comment: Change the calculation to double. Use a variable of declared type instead of `2#`. If the problem persists create an interim result to take control of the calculation sequence.

Comment: Use a `long` +/- 2G instead of a 16 bit signed integer +/- 32K. Note integers and longs CANNOT hold decimal points. Use a double instead of a single. If you didn't declare anything this is how they'd be treated anyway.

Comment: As to 2#.  If I type 2.0 into my editor, VB turns it into 2#.  I believe 2# is shorthand for CDbl(2).

Comment: You're correct. 2# forces it to be a double. However something in the calc is creating the overflow error. Suggest that you do what variatus suggests ... and break the calc apart, using explicit variables ... and find which part is triggering the error. While I could be wrong, I'm betting that temp ends up holding a value other 12 or 24 at some stage in the loop as CSng(3.14159 * 2# / CSng(12)) AND CSng(3.14159 * 2# / CSng(24)) do not generate errors. Which goes all the way back to Tim's original comment.

Comment: As suggested, forcing some interim calculations got me through this.  But I now have a similar issue down stream (that didn't exist before).  Just making everything Double didn't do it.  I had to force the a reorder of the calculation ... but exactly how was more trial and error than anything else.  A bit frustrating.  But thank you everyone for helping.